# What is the difference between NSURLRequest and URLRequest in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsurlrequest

I'm looking through some swift documents and I see that NSURLRequest and URLRequest are practically the same, with the added tidbit that NSURLRequest is used:

> when you need reference semantics or other Foundation-specific behavior.

Is one faster than the other and in what situations should one be used over the other?

Comment: If you are using Swift, you should use `URLRequest` as it was made using the Swift API Design Guidelines. Most Swift APIs use `URLRequest` now, so if you use `NSURLRequest` you'll have to typecast to `URLRequest`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`URLRequest` is an overlay for `NSURLRequest` so you are correct in thinking that they are essentially the same thing.  They *are* different classes but they are intended to provide the same functionality.  The NS version is more of a legacy API that was a holdover from Objective-C and the non-NS version is the 'swifty' one.

Here is a quote from apple's own documentation on [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest):

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the URLRequest structure, which bridges to the NSURLRequest class and its mutable > subclass, 
>   NSMutableURLRequest. For more information about value types, see [Working with Cocoa Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6) in [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 4)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216).

Additionally, here is the actual swift proposal from when they decided to drop NS from a number of classes with Foundation.

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md

Essentially, if you are using Objective-C you use the NS versions.  If you are using Swift you want to default to using the Non-NS versions and only use the NS version when you are trying to bridge to Objective-C or a specific library is requiring you to use the NS version.

Comment: You can see the source of URLRequest here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/URLRequest.swift

Answer (score 1):

Swift has a certain pattern in Foundation of wrapping some NS classes with Swift constructs. Examples of this include String (NSString), Array (NSArray), JSONSerialization (NSJSONSerialization), Date (NSDate), …

Use the wrapper whenever possible dropping down to the NS version only when needed. In this case, use URLRequest unless you run into problems.